# Запятая при обособленном определении

Tags: пунктуация, причастия, сложное-предложение

Есть предложение:

**Громкий хлопок раздавшийся когда он пробегал мимо комнаты своей дочери остановил его.**

То, что это СПП, и "когда он пробегал мимо комнаты своей дочери" нужно выделить запятыми, я поняла, а вот запятая перед "раздавшийся" нужна или нет? Или надо поставить её только перед "раздавшийся", а перед "когда..." она уже не нужна?

Comment: Если вам дан хороший ответ, отметьте его галочкой.

Answer (score 2):

**Громкий хлопок, раздавшийся, когда он пробегал мимо комнаты своей дочери, остановил его.**

Вам дан верный ответ, **все запятые придется поставить**, но вторая запятая является только **грамматической, паузы там нет**.

Поэтому вся конструкция не кажется корректной, она похожа **на дословный перевод**. И семантика неясна: хлопок раздался из комнаты или просто в то время, когда он пробегал мимо комнаты. Но все эти вопросы **по стилистике**, а не по пунктуации.

Comment: _Jasmin: ...но вторая запятая является только грамматической, **паузы там нет**._ ===  Не согласен. Я, к примеру, читаю это это предложение с паузой перед "когда".

Comment: Нормальная стилистика, если исходить из того, что здесь в одном предложении изложены две равные по значимости мысли: (1) Когда он пробегал мимо комнаты своей дочери, раздался громкий хлопок. (2) Этот хлопок остановил его.

Comment: Вот нормальная структура предложения, удобная для чтения,  она состоит из трех фраз примерно равного объема: Громкий хлопОк, вдруг раздавшийся из кОмнаты, остановИл его. Если увеличивать центральную часть, то читать сложнее, а при определенном объеме фраза перестает нормально  восприниматься.

Comment: Еще хуже, если ее осложнить, разбив на две части.  Ведь дело не только в паузах, но в ударении. Теперь  определение должно иметь два фазовых ударения, а это неверно. Создается впечатление, что это два однородных определения: Громкий хлопОк, раздАвшийся, когда он пробегал мимо комнаты своей дОчери, остановИл его. Поэтому приходится читать центр как одну фразу, очень неуклюжую.

Answer (score 1):

Верно:

> Громкий хлопок,(1) раздавшийся,(2) когда он пробегал мимо комнаты своей дочери,(3) остановил его.

1. Причастный оборот: «хлопок» — определяемое слово, после которого идет причастие «раздавшийся».
2. Придаточное времени, зависимое от главной части «раздавшийся» (то есть оно находится внутри причастного оборота).
3. Запятая, завершающая и придаточное предложение, и причастный оборот.